# Problem using custom JDBC driver to work with Zuul-Eureka Spring-Boot Applications which uses HTTP communications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, netflix-eureka

I have a set of Spring Boot applications which are communicating with each other through http calls and are registered in Eureka server.

One of those applications, say DBServices, interacts with Oracle DB. In this DB I am keeping some data of other Java applications, say consumers.
Now, I am trying to let consumers use their data in my Oracle DB by a custom JDBC driver (a wrapper over JDBC driver) that I am writing.

I am trying to find a way that when a consumer calls `createConnection()` or `executeQuery()` , my custom driver actually executes their query in 'DBServices' and return the result through resultset. Is this possible?

The question is mainly due to custom JDBC driver trying to interact with microservices which uses http / REST communications.

Comment: it depends upon how you configure data source.  I believe, you will have to extend data source class into your own class and configure your class instead of JDBC driver's data source class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to create a wrapper on the top of existing JDBC data source classes. It depends upon how you configure data source but I believe, you will have to extend data source class into your cutom class and configure your class instead of JDBC driver's data source standard class in the data source configuration.

Now in your custom data source class, you can override the createConnection or executeQuery function. Similarly, you may also need to consider overriding Statement, and PreparedStatements classes.

Also, there are lot static initialization in the JDBC driver classes, which you need to be considerate of. Along with that, if JDBC driver you are using.. has final classes then this approach wont work at all.

(Posting it as answer as comments can't have this long text )

Comment: JDBC driver itself works with JDBC URLs . My problem spricifically is , I am having HTTP calls in my micro-services app.

Comment: @AnkurB.Roy - Please be clear with your question. You can re-phrase your question